# Predominant vs. predominating

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between 'predominant' and 'predominating'? Which word would be used in this sentence:

> The opinion assigned to each community could represent the predominant/predominating opinion among the community members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Predominant* is a static attribute.

*Predominating* is an activity - meaning there is a predomination--or change in amount of predomination--in progress and we are talking about that as a "thing."

We can say "a predominating X" to mean X is becoming or looking like the predominat X.

> The predominant opinion about the school was that it sucked.

I asked a bunch of people and most people said the school sucked.  I am implying I am not asking more people about the school.

> The predominating opinion about the school was that it sucked.

So far, of everyone I have asked, most say the school sucked.  This could change as I ask more people.

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATE**

With this reference: [learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/).

I think it has no significant difference between those two words as an adjective for "opinion". Either of them will make it mean "an opinion that predominates".

===========================================================================

**OLD**

Predominant is an adjective. You can use it like that. So, "predominant opinion" is correct.

On the other hand, "predominating" is just a word (verb) "predominate" with -ing. Therefore, "predominating opinion" is incorrect.

See:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/predominant
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/predominate

Comment: From the examples in http://www.dictionary.com/browse/predominating, it seems to me that predominating is also an adjective, isn't it?

Comment: @Shayan I think this can describe what is happening here. https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/adjectives-ending-ed-and-ing. So, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: "predominating opinion" is ***not*** "incorrect". It's idiomatically far less common than "predominant opinion", but syntactically / grammatically it's no more invalid than, say, [*the **prevailing** opinion*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+prevailing+opinion%2Cthe+prevalent+opinion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20prevailing%20opinion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20prevalent%20opinion%3B%2Cc0) - which as that NGram link shows, is much more common than *the **prevalent** opinion*.